# Angular: sharedata between controller and directive. How $watch works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have some skills in JS and I'm almost newbee Angular. I have a question about how $watch works in my case. Task - share data between directive and controller in a proper way. As I understand, best practise is to share data using service. So I have:

directive

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('ffDomains', function(sharedData) {
...
    $scope.navigateTo = function(domain, event) {
        $scope.activeDomain = domain;
        sharedData.setDomain(domain);
    };
...
}
```

factory

```
angular.module("app.factories").factory('sharedData', function () {
    var domain = null;

    return {
        setDomain: setDomain,
        getDomain: getDomain
    };

    function setDomain(_domain) {
        domain = _domain;
    }

    function getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

});
```

and controller

```
angular.module('app.controllers').controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'sharedData', function ($scope, sharedData) {

    $scope.currentDomain = {};
    $scope.$watch(function() {return sharedData.getDomain()}, function() {

        if (sharedData.getDomain()) {
            $scope.currentDomain = sharedData.getDomain();
        } else {
            $scope.currentDomain.domain = 'All domains';
        }
    });

}]);
```

The question is Why I should use **function() {return sharedData.getDomain()}** instead of **sharedData.getDomain()** in watch? The last one is a link to *domain* variable in my service. Why is it not enough to whatch on it?

Kindly thanks for help. I appreciate your time.

Comment: You can try following `$scope.$watch(sharedData.getDomain,...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about your question:

> The question is Why I should use function() {return
>   sharedData.getDomain()} instead of sharedData.getDomain() in watch?
>   The last one is a link to domain variable in my service. Why is it not
>   enough to whatch on it?

As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should
>   return the value that will be watched. (watchExpression should not
>   change its value when executed multiple times with the same input
>   because it may be executed multiple times by $digest(). That is,
>   watchExpression should be idempotent.)

The `watchExpression` can be:

- a string
- a function

The "string" is a valid [AngulaJS expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). As described in the documentation:

> Angular expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following
>   differences:
>
> - **Context**: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a `scope` object.
>
> ...

So, if you specify a "string" in the `watchExpression`, AngularJS will evaluate the expression against the scope.

If you pass a `function` as `watchExpression`, the function will return the value to watch. The "function" is used every time the value to watch cannot be easily retrieved in the scope (otherwise you could use the "string" expression instead of "function" one).

In your example, the `watchExpression` is:

```
function() {return sharedData.getDomain()}
```

You `sharedData` service is not a variable defined in the scope (for example `$scope.sharedData = {...}`) but is a Angular service defined somewhere else. For this reason you have to use a function() as  `watchExpression`, otherwise Angular is not able to watch the domain for changes.

Comment: Thanks! I have an idea that the reason is than i'm trying to watch service that is outside current scope. I missed in documentation this point. And I missed that I should use callback in this case.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find that my answer or any other answer resolve your doubts, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you're referring to a factory, hence a variable outside the current scope.

When you pass a variable to the watcher, angular will evaluate the **string** inside the current scope and obviously it doesn't exist.

```
var domain sharedData.getDomain();
$scope.$watch('domain', function(newVal, oldVal) { 
//domain doesn't exist in the current scope

});
```

Everytime you want to watch something outside the current scope you have to provide a callback as a parameter that will be triggered during the dygest cycle.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return sharedData.getDomain()
}, function(newVal, oldVal) { 

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that it is small offtopic, but how dygest cycle initialazed? I read some docs, but do not understand for 100%. I know that is not a timer)
So is it correct, if I say that in this case angular watches at every variable (including my factory) and if variable in factory is changes - it looks at $watch (not only manually configured) variables in all related to this factory scopes?

Comment: The digest cycle it's a sort of loop that is executed periodically (for instance every x ms) by the core of angular, that triggers all the watchers of your app. For example the ng-click directive (and all angular directives) call themself the $scope.apply() that add the variable to the dygest cycle. this is  even valid for all the variable in your scope, on the contrary if you execute code "outside angular", for example native javascript (let's say setTimeout(..) ) , you must wrap the content inside a $scope.apply() that triggerrs itself the dygest cycle otherwise your model won't be updated.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot! And the last one question: is my approach correct to share data between controller and directive, or is there are more suitable approaches exist?

Comment: yes absolutely, it's a valid solution. i'm glad i helped you, i'd appreciate if you can give me a +1.